# How to Assert value assigned to ElementId in Selenium c#?

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, assertions

This is supposed to be easy, but somehow I couldn't get this to work as I would have liked to. I am trying to assert on ***Account value*** from below piece of code, which does have an ElementId assigned.

My aim is to verify that ***Account value*** is greater than zero (or can also do != zero)

I am confused whether to use the ***GetAttribute*** or shall I just extract the text out of the ElementId?

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 w-create-account">
<label class="w-label">Value</label>
<h2 id="account-value">$1,00,000</h2>
</div>
```

I am using Selenium(C#) on NUnit. Any help is appreciated..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something similar to following:

```
public static decimal ConvertToNumber(string str)
{
    return decimal.Parse(str, NumberStyles.Currency);
}


[Test]
public void TestAccountValue()
{

    Assert.IsTrue(ConvertToNumber(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'w-create-account']/h2")).Text) > 0, "Account value is not greater than zero.");

}
```

Let me know, if you have any further queries.

Comment: Thanks, it is working fine for me. I just had to initiate the _Namespace_ for **using System.Globalization** and thereafter could call _NumberStyles_

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below logic for the assertion

**Code:**

```
var accountValue=driver.FindElement(By.Id("account-value")).Text;
accountValue = accountValue.Substring(1);//Inorder to remove the currency symbol.

var amount = Decimal.Parse(accountValue);

Assert.IsTrue(amount > 0);//If the Amount value is greater than 0, then assertion wil be passed.
```

Suppose, if the account value holds negative balance as well, then replace the substring statement with the below condition

```
var accountValue=driver.FindElement(By.Id("account-value")).Text;

if (accountValue.Contains('-')){
    accountValue = "-" + accountValue.Substring(2);//Inorder to remove the currency symbol and negative sign
}
else
{
    accountValue = accountValue.Substring(1);//Inorder to remove the currency symbol.
}

var amount=Decimal.Parse(accountValue);

Assert.IsTrue(amount > 0);//If the Amount value is greater than 0, then assertion wil be passed.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this one in pricing services:

```
Assert.Greater(Convert.ToDouble(driver.FindElement(By.Id("account-value")).Text), 0,  
 "Acccount value is zero 0");
```

-- it means, if Account value is zero, it failed.

or if you want to add assert for zero. it could be like:

```
string accountValue = driver.FindElement(By.Id("account-value")).Text;  
Assert.IsFalse(accountValue.Contains("0"), "Account value is zero");
```

-- I hope it is displayed as text, if not, you need to use `.GetAttribute("value")` = number.